# $ (a-b)^- \le a^-+b^+ $ where $x:=x^+-x^-$ and $x^+=max(x,0)$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

The following question comes from a seemingly trivial passage from a book of Stochastic Processes (it is used in a upcrossing inequality). I solved it with case checking, but I am hoping there is a better way to prove it, which I couldn't find..

**Problem:** Given a real number $x$, we say that $x=x^+-x^-$ where $x^+=\max(x,0)$. Prove that for all reals $a,b$ it holds
$$
(a-b)^- \le a^-+b^+.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(a-b)^-=\max\{b-a,0\}\leq \max\{b,0\}+\max\{-a,0\}=b^++a^-.$$

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice properties with $x^+$ and $x^-$ that you may easily deduce. For example:

1. $(a+b)^+ \le a^+ + b^+$ (convexity)
2. $(-a)^+ = a^-$ (symmetry)

My way is to always convert the minus signs to to plus signs.

In your case, it is

$$(a-b)^-=(b-a)^+=(b+(-a))^+\le b^++(-a)^+=b^++a^-.$$